# What type of "medical insurance" is needed for a short stay visa to Romania?

Tags: visas, standard-visitor-visas, health, insurance, romania

For Romanian visa type C/VV papers, the embassy requires a "Travel Medical Insurance"

I tried searching for that online, but I am confused which type am I supposed to apply for.

I am staying in Romania for three months or less.

Is the type of insurance needed an ordinary "Travel insurance"?

Or is it an international health insurance?

I tried asking the Embassy but they keep referring me to the online portal, which doesn't clarify as much.

I am from Egypt.

Comment: Any insurance which will cover your health costs if you get ill in Romania. It may be a travel insurance (but often they limit on duration or purpose of travel). The details? You should ask your insurance. There is not standardized policy (also within a single country).

Comment: A travel insurance policy covering €30000 is the standard requirement for Schengen. And as Romania is in the EU, I'd assume the requirement is the same

Comment: Typically I will just go to a travel insurance company and say "I need the mandatory medical insurance for a short stay in Romania" and they will know exactly what is needed because that's their job.